# Needing help solving DatePiker problems

Tags: java, android

I'm currently making a simple app for reports and one of the things I'm trying to make is a small callendar, basically a image that will show the DatePiker options once clicked, then put the informed date on a EditText for the user to see, but I'm facing a "Cannot resolve symbol 'DatePiker'" I don't know why this is happening, this code was working perfecly one hour ago.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.fragment.app.DialogFragment;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.DatePickerDialog;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Patterns;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.AwesomeValidation;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.ValidationStyle;
import com.basgeekball.awesomevalidation.utility.RegexTemplate;

import java.util.Calendar;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText ntnome, ntdocumento, nttelefone, ntemail, carcor, carplaca, carmarca, ocdata, ochora,
            ocdescrição;
    static EditText editTextDataOC;
    Button ocenvio;
    ImageView imageViewDataOC;

    AwesomeValidation awesomeValidation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        imageViewDataOC = findViewById(R.id.oc_calendar);
        editTextDataOC = findViewById(R.id.oc_data);
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        Integer dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        Integer mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        Integer ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        editTextDataOC.setText(dia + "/" + mes + "/" + ano);

        imageViewDataOC.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                DialogFragment dialogFragment = new calendario.DatePiker();
                dialogFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DataInicial");
            }
        });
    }

    public static class DatePicker extends DialogFragment implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

        @Override
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
            Integer dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            Integer mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            Integer ano = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);

            DatePickerDialog datePickerHoloLight = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(),
                    AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT, this, ano, mes, dia);

            return datePickerHoloLight;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(android.widget.DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
            String tagClicada = getTag();

            if(tagClicada.equals("imageViewDataOC")){
                editTextDataOC.setText(day + "/" + month + "/" + year);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: if the problem is on the onclicklistener of imageviewdataOC, it is because you are calling calendario.DatePicker.
calendario is of type Calendar and there is no method DatePicker there https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar

Comment: Do you mean `class DatePicker` - typo?

Comment: Check this line:

 DialogFragment dialogFragment = new calendario.DatePicker();
you were missing 'c'. while calling DatePicker() class

Comment: It was both the typo and the Calendar method, thanks for bringing this to my attention, apparently I'm losing my ability to read.